# Solving multilib version problems

Tags: installation, centos, 32bit-64bit, rpm, yum

I use Centos 7

When I tried to install libstdc++ with yum install libstdc++.i686 I took following massages.

```
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
       cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
       pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

         1. You have an upgrade for libstdc++ which is missing some
            dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
            solve this by installing an older version of libstdc++ of the
            different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
            yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
            requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
            --exclude libstdc++.otherarch ... this should give you an error
            message showing the root cause of the problem.

         2. You have multiple architectures of libstdc++ installed, but
            yum can only see an upgrade for one of those architectures.
            If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
            can remove the one with the missing update and everything
            will work.

         3. You have duplicate versions of libstdc++ installed already.
            You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

       ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
       this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
       do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
       much more problems).

       Protected multilib versions: libstdc++-4.8.5-39.el7.i686 != libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7_6.2.x86_64
```

How can I install **libstdc++.i686**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it helped me

```
yum update -y libstdc++.x86_64
yum install libstdc++.i686
```

Comment: For future readers, what was wrong is that OP was trying to install a _different_ 32-bit version of `libstdc++` than the installed 64-bit (because `yum install` was getting the newest). The multilib protections in RPM prevent this; they (32 and 64) must always match versions (since they share headers,etc.). I _think_ `yum upgrade libstdc++.{x86_64,i686}` might have worked, but not positive off-hand.

Answer (score 1):

do you have try this

yum update --setopt=protected_multilib=false

Comment: Do you think that your proposal could possibly corrupt applications? A user without commenting privilege has had problems. Please elaborate on possible risks you see with your solution.